# git see history of a specific c function that has a prototype above it in the source file

Tags: c, git, git-diff, git-log, gitattributes

I am trying to see the history of a c function using git log, but the function is static and the source code is organized with a block of function prototypes at the top, and their definitions are below in the source code.

Something like this:

```c
/// @file foo.c

static void foo();

static void foo()
{
    // function body
}
```

I am trying to see the history like I would with an external function (the prototype would be in a separate header file):

```
git log -L :foo:foo.c
```

However when I do this it only shows me the history for the prototype. I am only interested in the functions implementation. Is there a way I can see the history for the actual definition?

I have already done some searching and attempted to set up a `.gitattributes` file in the base directory of my repo with these contents:

```
*.c diff=cpp
*.h diff=cpp
*.f diff=fortran
```

Any ideas what else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the spec for identifying functions in C-family files also matches a declaration. So write your own, you know what you're looking for so you could just give it literally,

```
git log -L '/^static void foo()$/,/^}/':foo.c
```

or get cute and say something like (smoketested so at least not *completely* wrong:)

```
git log -L '/^\([[:alnum:]_]\+[[:space:]]\)*foo(.*)$/,/^}/':foo.c
```

Comment: Thanks this  works great for a single function.

I am going to try to extend this to be clean for any function name. That's where I would want to use the .gitattributes file right?